# Search and get content from data in XML and then place that value in another tag using powershell

Tags: powershell

Sample text file contains:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Document xmlns ="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.056.001.01" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<FIToFIPmtCxlReq>
<Assgnmt>
<Id>ID123456</Id>
<Assgnr>
<Agt>
<FinInstnId>
<BIC>BICSEND</BIC>
</FinInstnId>
</Agt>
</Assgnr>
<Assgne>
<Agt>
<FinInstnId>
<BIC>BICRCV</BIC>
</FinInstnId>
</Agt>
</Assgne>
<CreDtTm>2020-12-16T09:05:15.0Z</CreDtTm>
</Assgnmt>
<CtrlData>
<NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
<CtrlSum>0</CtrlSum>
</CtrlData>
<Undrlyg>
<TxInf>
<CxlId>20201216.105.19344855940590400</CxlId>
<OrgnlGrpInf>
<OrgnlMsgId>REF123456789</OrgnlMsgId>
<OrgnlMsgNmId>pacs.008</OrgnlMsgNmId>
</OrgnlGrpInf>
<OrgnlInstrId>FT123456</OrgnlInstrId>
<OrgnlEndToEndId>NOTPROVIDED</OrgnlEndToEndId>
<OrgnlTxId>20201216.100.02202020</OrgnlTxId>
<OrgnlIntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">25.23</OrgnlIntrBkSttlmAmt>
<OrgnlIntrBkSttlmDt>2020-12-16</OrgnlIntrBkSttlmDt>`
```

Please be informed that I would like to code PowerShell to extract the data in tag `<OrgnlIntrBkSttlmAmt>` (please note that the data length can change since this is an amount field) and then replace the "0" in tag `<CtrlSum>` with "25.23".

Can someone help me with this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should show us more of the xml. PowerShell is very capable of manipulating xml, but the way you describe what you want, you leave no other choice than to do string replacements..

Comment: @Theo thank you for your comment. I have provided xml exactly as it is on file. Thank you once again for your review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml you show us is invalid as it is missing the following closing tags:

```
        </TxInf>
    </Undrlyg>
</FIToFIPmtCxlReq>
</Document>
```

If I add these, you could do this to update the value in the `<CtrlSum>` tag:

```
# load the xml from file
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\test.xml' -Raw
# get the amount from the 'OrgnlIntrBkSttlmAmt' tag
$amount = $xml.Document.FIToFIPmtCxlReq.Undrlyg.TxInf.OrgnlIntrBkSttlmAmt.'#text'

# use that amount to put in the 'CtrlSum' tag
$xml.Document.FIToFIPmtCxlReq.CtrlData.CtrlSum = $amount

# save the updated xml to file
$xml.Save('D:\Test\test.xml')
```

Comment: First of all apologies for not giving the full XML tags. Thank you for your help. Just wanted to let you know that the script worked perfectly. :)

Comment: once the process is complete i want to save the file as a text file and not xml....may you kindly advise what i need to do to get this result? Thanks